# Hi..I need to read all contacts and convert it as .vcf file

Tags: android, android-contacts

In My program am trying to read all contacts and convert it as .vcf file.When i run the app,contacts  are converted  into .vcf file and printed in the console and get stored in the memory.But my app unfortunately stops.It get crashed.Please help me.I wonder even though i get the output why my app is crashed...Here i need to know why my app unfortunately stops in-spite of getting the exact output

my code:

```
package com.example.ip.newvcf;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> vCard;
    Context mContext;
    final String vfile = "lll.vcf";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mContext=this;

       // final String vfile = "POContactsRestore.vcf";

        Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

        phones.moveToFirst();
        for(int i =0;i<phones.getCount();i++)
        {
            String lookupKey =  phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

            AssetFileDescriptor fd;
            try
            {
                fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                fis.read(buf);
                String VCard = new String(buf);
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + vfile;
                FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
                mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
                phones.moveToNext();
                Log.d("Vcard",  VCard);
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

My error Log:

```
09-11 08:23:22.329 25017-25017/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
09-11 08:23:22.329 25017-25017/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.example.ip.newvcf [ userId:0 | appId:10740 ]
09-11 08:23:22.469 25017-25017/com.example.ip.newvcf E/InstantRun: Could not find slices in APK; aborting.
09-11 08:23:22.679 25017-25017/com.example.ip.newvcf E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
09-11 08:23:46.169 25017-25017/com.example.ip.newvcf E/Looper: Error adding epoll events for fd -24, errno=9
09-11 08:23:46.179 25017-25017/com.example.ip.newvcf E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.ip.newvcf, PID: 25017
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize display event receiver.  status=-2147483648
       at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.nativeInit(Native Method)
       at android.view.DisplayEventReceiver.<init>(DisplayEventReceiver.java:61)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.<init>(Choreographer.java:747)
       at android.view.Choreographer.<init>(Choreographer.java:177)
       at android.view.Choreographer.<init>(Choreographer.java:73)
       at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:99)
       at android.view.Choreographer$1.initialValue(Choreographer.java:92)
       at java.lang.ThreadLocal$Values.getAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:430)
       at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:65)
       at android.view.Choreographer.getInstance(Choreographer.java:202)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:492)
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:267)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3184)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2505)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:171)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: sir..how to clear the error.Please explain in detail.I referred tutorials but i didn't get the answer

Comment: Sir am getting my exact output...But my app crashes..And i didn't understand the answer mentioned in that page.Please help me

Comment: No idea who closed it, as the only thing in common is the Exception description, and there is no working answer there! As for your issue, I guess it is because you are doing too much on the main thread, and you are not allowing onCreate to return. On an emulator, there is much more  speed and less contacts, thus  it finished quick enough..You should move the code to create the vcf to an AsyncTask, thus allowing the main thread to continue.